# accessing m3u8 lists with url parameters in Chromecast

Tags: chromecast, google-cast

Is there a way to retain the url parameters sending to chromecast even while accessing the child items in an m3u8 list ? Because we require url parameters to access the content or media file but chromecast truncates the url parameters we send while accessing the child file.

Example
given url: http://domainname.com/1.m3u8?cp=%2FsFcurrent%2F70000871V%2F*&cf=1403&e=1493&h=cbc90

the file 1.m3u8 contains child files like 1med.m3u8, 1high.m3u8 1low.m3u8

while chromecast access the child file, it accesses like http://domainname.com/1med.m3u8

As you can notice, it removed the url parameters, this results in child file not being accessible.

Answer (score 0):

You need to write a custom receiver (using MPL) and use host overrides updateManifestRequestInfo / updateSegmentRequestInfo to achieve the desired behavior.

Comment: In the https://developers.google.com/cast/docs/reference/player/cast.player.api.RequestInfo  , there is content, content protection, headers, timeoutinterval, url and with credentials as properties for class cast.player.api.RequestInfo(), in this which property should we use to send our url parameters to be retained while accessing child files.